# Squid authentication encryption

Tags: ssl, squid

I use Squid and the users must authenticate. The users are authenticating in cleartext. I found tutorials about stunnel (http://www.jeffyestrumskas.com/?page_id=3), but the clients also need this software.

Is there no possibility that for user authentication SSL (or some other encryption technology) can be used?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://squid-web-proxy-cache.1019090.n4.nabble.com/Simple-Kerberos-Squid-configuration-received-type-1-NTLM-token-td2553379.html#a2553379.

Using SSO (Kerberos) with Firefox as client (on a Windows Xp client and Linux server with Kerberos and no AD and no LDAP if not needed) is a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could use HTTP Digest authentication with squid. This way the passwords would not be passed clear-text. This is quite easy to configure, no certificated needed, little overhead. I have successfully used it for some time in a small company.

There are some problems with this approach, though:

- Many HTTP clients have digest authentication implementation broken.
- You will probably not be able to use your current ('encrypted') password database.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an ACL using the [**user_cert ACL Type**](http://www.visolve.com/squid/squid26/accesscontrols.php#user_cert) in squid.conf.

```
acl ssl_authentication user_cert somecertattributevalue
```

Then create filters using that ACL.

```
http_access deny all
http_access allow ssl_authentication
```

Comment: Can you give more information? Where must the "user_cert" option be used. Nothing on the internet about this, besides the few paragrpahes int he documentation (http://www.visolve.com/squid/squid26/accesscontrols.php#user_cert).

Comment: @barbarossa12d: sorry, I forgot to include that!  It goes in the acl directive.  I've edited to include.

Comment: I have: "acl myacl user_cert src 192.168.1.5"

It gives at startup the following error:
aclParseAclLine: Invalid ACL type 'user_cert'.

I am using Squid 2.7 on Debian.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Anyone? Just an example will do it.